# Calling a modal when clicking on a hyperlink inside a table

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have the following HTML code-

```
<div id="one">
    <div class="card shadow mb-4" style="width:98%;margin-left:1%;">
        <div class="card-header py-3">
            <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">XXXXXXXXXXXXXX</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body" style="width:100%;">
            <table id="table_id" class="order-column">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>AAAAAAAAAAA</th>
                    <th>BBBBBBBBBBB</th>
                    <th>CCCCCCCCCCC</th>
                    <th>ObjectLink</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {% for ele in data %}
                <tr>
                    {% for k,v in ele.items%}
                    {%ifnotequal k fail %}
                    <td>{{v}}</td>
                    {%else%}

                    <td style="text-decoration: underline;color:blue;"><a href="#mymodal" data-toggle="modal">Object</a></td>
                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="mymodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
                         aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
                         aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="vertical-alignment-helper">
                            <div class="modal-dialog vertical-align-center">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        </button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Object Content</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <p>{{v}}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                                            Close
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    {% endifnotequal%}
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here when I click on the "object" hyperlink, it should display me a value which is different for different rows. Problem I am facing is, all the hyperlinks shows the content of first row only.

My question may be similar/duplicate of [How can I click on a table cell and display a modal with notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21461440/how-can-i-click-on-a-table-cell-and-display-a-modal-with-notes) but I was not able to implement that in my code, If any body can help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it worked by using "forloop.counter", below is the code for the  same-

```
<div class="card shadow mb-4" style="width:98%;margin-left:1%;">
        <div class="card-header py-3">
            <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body" style="width:100%;">
            <table id="table_id" class="order-column">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</th>
                    <th>BBBBBBBBBBBBB</th>
                    <th>CCCCCCCCCCCCC</th>
                    <th>ObjectLink</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {% for ele in data %}
                {% with my_var=forloop.counter %}

                <tr>
                    {% for k,v in ele.items%}

                    {%ifnotequal k fail %}
                    <td>{{v}}</td>
                    {%else%}
                    <td style="text-decoration: underline;color:blue;"><a href="#mymodal{{my_var}}" data-toggle="modal">Object</a></td>
                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="mymodal{{my_var}}" tabindex="-1" data-replace="true" role="dialog"
                         aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
                         aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="vertical-alignment-helper">
                            <div class="modal-dialog vertical-align-center">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        </button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Object Content</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <p>{{v}}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                                            Close
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    {% endifnotequal%}
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
                {% endwith %}
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Cheers!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what templating system you're using but I see this thing inside you loop:

```
<a href="#mymodal" data-toggle="modal">Object</a>
...
<div class="modal fade" id="mymodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" ...
```

You see, inside the loop you're recreating same anchor with the same div with same id id="mymodal". So I'll try to gues the syntax here, but you need something like this:

```
<a href="#mymodal{{k}}" data-toggle="modal">Object</a>
....
<div class="modal fade" id="mymodal{{k}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" ...
```

Now your foreach already splits the array to key => value

```
{% for k,v in ele.items%}
```

Inside the loop where you generate your ancho and div you'll add the key to the div id - id="mymodal{{k}}" and for anchor href - href="#mymodal{{k}}" This should do the trick

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this didn't help...Problem still persists.

Comment: I am using django templates.

Comment: So is the problem solved? Cause I don't see any other issue with the code ...

Comment: No, the problem still persists, Modal Content is same for all hyperlinks.

Comment: so now you have different Ids for modals? Can you check this in debugger?

Comment: try to modify id="myModalLabel" to id="myModalLabel{{k}}" as well

Comment: sorry, can you tell me how to use debugger... Also I changed the "myModalLabel{{k}}", didnt help.

Comment: My key value (k variable in for loop) is always same. I tried giving {{v}} in place of {{k}} didn't work.